# How to open a file by clicking a link from a jsp which is in a protected share folder?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jcifs

I have tried to write a file on a protected share folder using **JCIFS (SmbFile)** concept. Following is the code snippet that I've tried and successfully write a file on a protected folder:

```
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
String protectedFolder = "smb://machineName/protectedFolderName";
String fileName = "SampleFile.xls";
String filePath = protectedFolder + fileName;
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(username  + ":" +   
password);
SmbFile protectedFile = new SmbFile(strTemplate, auth);
SmbFileOutputStream fileOut = new SmbFileOutputStream(protectedFile);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();

The above code successfully creates 'SampleFile.xls' in the protected folder.
```

If I want to open that file from a jsp page by clicking a link (href), how I can perform the above mentioned JCIFS authentication?
Any thoughts on this are appreciable.

Thanks.

Comment: Well I guess you could just create a simple Servlet that does this for you?

Comment: Yes! I am trying that. I'll update the status.